# Proving a complex inequality in polar form

Tags: complex-analysis

$$ |e^z -1| \leq e^{|z|} -1 \leq |z|e^{|z|} $$ for all $ z \in C $.

My solution for the left inequality: $$ |e^z -1| \leq e^{|z|} -1$$
By triangle inequality $$ |e^z -1| \leq |e^z| -|1|$$
Therefore $$ |e^z -1| \leq e^{|z|} -1$$

I had a problem proving the second inequality: $$ e^{|z|} -1 \leq |z|e^{|z|} $$

I tried substituting $e^z = e^x (\cos y + i \sin y)$ and $|z| = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} $ but after 2 pages of manipulations, I got back where I started, only messier forms. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the change of variables $z = Re^{i\theta}$ could help? You'd have $|z| = R$.

Comment: I tried that. I got $ -R <= \frac {1}{e^R} -1 $ which is also a dead end :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second inequality concerns real numbers only. So you have to prove
$$
e^x-1\le xe^x
$$
for any $x\ge0$. Dividing through by $e^x$, this is the same as
$$
1-e^{-x}\le x,
$$
which is the same as the well-known inequality
$$e^{-x}\ge 1-x.$$

Comment: How do I prove the last known inequality? I used the Taylor expansion for $e^{-x}$ but it is an alternating series.

Comment: Prove the result $e^x\ge 1+x$, which is valid for all $x$, using the mean value theorem: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/605949/215011

Comment: One last question. I have used $ |e^z| = e^{|z|}  $ because I remember seeing that somewhere. I tried to prove it but I failed miserably when I substituted $ e^z = e^x(\cos y + i \sin y) $ is there a way to prove that?

Comment: It's not true. For example if $z=a+bi$ with $a$, $b$ real then $|e^{a+bi}|=e^a$ but $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ which in general is not the same as $|a|$.

Comment: I tried substituting $e^z = e^x(\cos \theta + i \sin theta) $ and it did not work. does it need manipulation before I substitute?

Comment: If you write $z=x+iy$ then $e^z=e^x(\cos y +i\sin y)$ so $|e^z|=e^x$. Since $x\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=|z|$, the most you can prove is $|e^z|\le e^{|z|}$ (you cannot prove equality).

Comment: Your proof of the left inequality is incorrect (the triangle inequality doesn't run the right way). See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1488241/215011

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For the second inequality  note that $|z|\ge 0$ so you have to prove that $y= e^x-xe^x-1\le 0$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

Take the derivative:
$$
y'=e^x(1-x) -e^x=-xe^x
$$
and note that $y'=0$ for $x=0$ and $y(0)=0$ and this is a maximum since $y \to -\infty$ for $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: I think you meant that we have to prove that $y <= 0$ in the first line. Correct?

Comment: Yes (I edit), but really it the same. When we find where $y\ge 0$, generally we also find where $y\le 0$.